# flow only using refinement after adding meaningless assignment

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In function `f`, flow complains that an object is not callable at `x(y)`. However, `x` can't be an object at this point, due to the type refinement.

In function `g`, adding an assignment `z = x` resolve the issue, but is functionally the same.

```
/* @flow */
'use strict';

function f(x: {} | (a: number) => number) {
    if (typeof x === 'object') {
        return x;
    }
    return (y: number) => x(y);
}

function g(x: {} | (a: number) => number) {
    if (typeof x === 'object') {
        return x;
    }
    var z = x;
    return (y: number) => z(y);
}

module.exports = {f, g};
```

What's going on? There's no function call here that would invalidate the refinement.

Comment: Add it to the looong list: https://github.com/facebook/flow/issues (include a https://flow.org/try/ link -- would be handy for your SO question as well)

Comment: I tried it with a disjoint union and it still doesn't work. This is, among other related issues with refinements/case analysis, the proof that you have to build the type system first and then the language around it, not the other way around.